# replace/change inline image url with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the image 1 to image 2 in a wordpress theme on mobile size.
the image is inline in the theme, so I can't replace it with background image and use media queries to get this done.

From:

```html
<a class="logo">
  <img src="image1.jpg">
</a>
```

Change to:

```html
<a class="logo">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
</a>
```

Any way I can do this?
I prefer CSS

Comment: SO is not a free coding service! Please share what you have tried so far ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following -

```css
.logo {
    content:url("image2.jpg");
}
```

Using breakpoints (depends on what CSS processor you are using like Stylus, SASS)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .logo{
        content:url("image2.jpg");
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo{
        content:url("image2.jpg");
    }
}
```